# Allow form editing on the display page in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

What would be the best way to collect data in a form on the main page of a wordpress installation and then display that data later?
Is there such a plugin?
I'd like to avoid allowing users to log on to the admin part, just have them enter data directly on the front page.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually fairly trivial to write your own code to do this, especially since WP provides plenty of features for data integrity checking, sanitation, and security. There's a plugin here that does various data capture things: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-email-capture/ that might work on your version but to be honest I've spent far more unhappy hours debugging and customising other peoples' plugins to do what I want than I have just writing something from scratch myself in the first place.

You may want to familiarise yourself with the WP plugin development section of the Codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin

Comment: "I've spent far more unhappy hours debugging and customising other peoples' plugins to do what I want than I have just writing something from scratch myself in the first place" - amen to that!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution in the form of a plugin called TDO Mini Forms.
It allows for creation of custom forms with a very fine control of things and lots of options.